# How To hide bottom view of position is absolute when keyboard is active in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: help me solve this****strong text]

I tried to hide the bottom view which position is absolute. I just wanted to hide it. pls help me .

Comment: Can you elaborate, like which view, and add an image without the keyboard.

Comment: [react-native-keyboard-listener](https://github.com/alexmngn/react-native-keyboard-listener) will help you if you can manipulate the css in StyleSheet.

Answer (score 5):

we need to Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in our manifest file, and it will work as we expect.

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  ...
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    ...
  </activity>
  ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyboard listener
import keyboard from react-native

```
     const keyboardShowListener = Keyboard.addListener( 
            'keyboardDidShow', 
            () => { 
                
     setIskeyboardOpen(true)
            } 
        ); 
   

 const keyboardHideListener = Keyboard.addListener( 
        'keyboardDidHide', 
        () => { 
           
setIskeyboardOpen(false)
        }
```

and  make like this:

```
{iskeyboardOpen && (<View></View>)}
```